# ElasticSearch doesn't work when multiple words don't have space

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

When I'm trying to search using `Loremipsum` it's returning empty array. I would like to get `Lorem ipsum dolor` using `Loremipsum` query.

value

```
Lorem ipsum dolor
```

query

```
GET favorite_candy/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Loremipsum"
    }
  }
}
```

result

```
"hits" : [ ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because there is no correspondence between the search token and the indexed tokens. In other words, the term "Loremipsum" does not find any corresponding token.

In my experience I see this as the possibility of using "did you mean". Once the term is incorrect, you can return suggestions for correct terms to the user.

In this case I did a test with Completion Suggestion. Note that I used the "[preserve_separators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester-mapping)" property so that you will get suggestions when you type the words together.

Query

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "suggest": {
        "type": "completion",
        "preserve_separators": false
      }
    }
  }
}


PUT idx_test/_doc/1
{
  "suggest": ["Lorem ipsum dolor"]
}


GET idx_test/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "any-suggest": {
      "prefix": "loremipsum",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
"suggest": {
    "any-suggest": [
      {
        "text": "loremipsum",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 10,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "_index": "idx_test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "suggest": [
                "Lorem ipsum dolor"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```